# Missing characters when executing hotkey

Tags: wordpress, autohotkey

I am writing a hotkey shortcut to hightlight text in Wordpress. The code is this:

```
^f2::
Send, ^x [su_highlight background="#DDFF99" color="#008000" class=""] ^v [/su_highlight]
return
```

However when I execute it on a string, let's call it string1, it returns

[su_highlight background="DDFF99" color="08000" class=""] string1 [/su_highlight].

Can anyone explain why the "#" disappears as well as one of the 0s for color and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add onto the other answer, I would recommend the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text) as opposed to any other mode. Because it can be used in combination with [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail), which is the recommended faster and more reliable send mode.

So:

```
^F2::
    SendInput, ^x
    SendInput, {Text}[su_highlight background="#DDFF99" color="#008000" class=""] 
    SendInput, ^v 
    SendInput, [/su_highlight]
return
```

Although, this is starting to get a bit long to send via a send command (in my opinion).
Consider utilizing the clipboard more to get an even faster and more reliable option:

```
^F2::
    Clipboard := "" ;empty the clipboard first
    
    ;send ctrl+x (cut), ctrl+v could be used in most text editors as well
    SendInput, ^x
    
    ;wait for the clipboard to contain something
    ;this is not required and it will likely work without it
    ;but it's kind of recommended I guess
    ClipWait 
    
    ;set the clipboard to contain what we want
    Clipboard := "[su_highlight background=""#DDFF99"" color=""#008000"" class=""""]" Clipboard "[/su_highlight]"
    
    ;send ctrl+v
    SendInput, ^v 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the '#' is treated as the Windows key when using 'Send', so you need to escape it

From [The #EscapeChar Documentation page](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm):

> When the Send command or Hotstrings are used in their default
> (non-raw) mode, characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning.
> Therefore, to use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
> braces. For example: Send {^}{!}{{}.

So, the modified code would be:

```
^f2::
Send ^x [su_highlight background="{#}DDFF99" color="{#}008000" class=""] ^v [/su_highlight]
return
```

EDIT: Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with having to change out certain characters whenever you want to type a literal # (or other affected character), you could use the SendRaw command instead.

For instance:

Using separate Sends for commands and text

```
^f2::
Send ^x
SendRaw [su_highlight background="#DDFF99" color="#008000" class=""] 
Send ^v 
SendRaw [/su_highlight]
return
```

For more info about SendRaw, here is [the Documentation link for SendRaw](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendRaw).